# Integrated google form in website won't open on macs but works on PCs. Error message "forms.gle refused to connect."

Tags: google-forms

I made a website and put a google form in it. It works flawlessly on pcs, but not on Macs or iphones for some reason. Depending on the browser it will not appear at all, or show the error message "forms.gle refused to connect." Please let me know what I should do to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was because I used the short link for the embed.  Changing to the full link fixed it for me.

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/77815684/tried-to-fill-out-a-google-docs-forum-but-gives-me-an-error-when-i-click-on-link?hl=en&msgid=78141638